# I can't get data from get set auto data property c#

Tags: c#

I'm a Student struggling and working for our System, and the code I used can't the data needed

first form

```
   public int transactionNo { get; set; }
   public int processNo { get;  set; }
```

and here's my code to get the data:

from a button click event

```
    transactionNo = int.Parse(lblTRANSACTIONO.Text);
    processNo = int.Parse(lblprocessNO.Text);
```

the lblTRANSACTIONO.Text and lblprocessNO has the right value,

and here's how I get the data to use it on labels of another form:

second form from the load event

```
   FORMtransactionADD FtA = new FORMtransactionADD();//first form
   lblTNo.Text = FtA.transactionNo.ToString();
   lblPNo.Text = FtA.processNo.ToString();
```

here's the output:
[image]

dont mind the 2017000 because it is the default text of those labels

The code doesn't work, is there any other way of setting auto data and getting it?

Comment: How do you set the data in the `other form`. Do you call the assignment? `lblTNo.Text = ...` are those two lines really called?

Comment: What is `FtA`? How are you creating it? What does _The code doesn't work_ means? Does it throw any error?

Comment: another thing: convention is to use  capital first letter on properties

Comment: Could you explain it further? Thanks.

Comment: @Pikoh the first form

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass data in other forms constructor.

Comment: Thanks pal! I'll try.